# Retrive objects from a list and teleport them to a specific location in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

and thank you for looking at this in advance.

#### I have yet another problem that i need to solve and it goes like this:

I have a list of objects that i select with a raycast, and i would like to teleport them to a specific location in the scene. Like for example i have selected a cube and a sphere and they are added to my list called playersTagged.

How can i get the objects in my list to that specific location when OnCollisionEnter with my player that has the tag "Tagger"?

My code looks like this:

PlayerTagged Class

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerTagged : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float damage = 10f;
    public float range = 100f;


    public Camera fpsCam;

    public List<GameObject> playersTagged;

    private void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1"))
        {
            Shoot();
        }
    }

    void Shoot()
    {
        RaycastHit hit;

        if (Physics.Raycast(fpsCam.transform.position, fpsCam.transform.forward, out hit, range))
        {
            Debug.Log(hit.transform.name);
            Target target = hit.transform.GetComponent<Target>();

            if (target != null && target.isHit == false)
            {
                target.takeDamage(damage);
                if(hit.collider.tag == "Taggable")
                playersTagged.Add(hit.collider.gameObject);
                target.isHit = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Teleport class:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class Teleport : MonoBehaviour
{

public Transform teleportTarget;
public PlayerTagged player;

private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{

    if (other.gameObject.tag == "Tagger")
    {
        Debug.Log("You hit the can");
    }

}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have the PlayerTagged reference in your Teleport component. If both objects will always exist in your scene, only create a public field in your Teleport and drag and drop your PlayerTagged ref, otherwise you will need to fill this ref by code using some "find" approach, for example, `GameObject.FindObjectWithTag()`.

You can also make an event that trigger when the object that entered the OnTriggerEnter is valid (I mean, when your tag condition pass) and then make sure that PlayerTagged is being registered as listener to this event.

First one is easier to setup, but if you plan to make unique things with this OnTriggerEnter as playing sounds, changing data or something like that, the second one is a better approach.

EDIT: I'll try to insert some code, let me know if you still having problems on getting the idea

"If both objects will always exist in your scene..."

```
using UnityEngine;

public class Teleport : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform teleportTarget;
    public PlayerTagged player; // I didn't saw that you already have an ref here, my bad, so you only need to access the fields

    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {

        if (other.gameObject.tag == "Tagger")
        {
            Debug.Log("You hit the can");
            
            var list = player.playersTagged; // this is how you will access your list

            // Do some stuff with your list
        }

    }

}
```

Ignore the rest, it will only complicate things

EDIT 2: Making the teleport happen in player, and teleport every object

```
    using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerTagged : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float damage = 10f;
    public float range = 100f;


    public Camera fpsCam;

    public List<GameObject> playersTagged;

    private void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1"))
        {
            Shoot();
        }
    }
    
    // Option 1:
    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider col)
    {
        if (col.gameObject.tag == "Teleport Tag")
        {
            var teleport = col.gameObject.GetComponent<Teleport>();
            
            TeleportObjectsTo(teleport.teleportTarget.position);
        }
    }

    void Shoot()
    {
        RaycastHit hit;

        if (Physics.Raycast(fpsCam.transform.position, fpsCam.transform.forward, out hit, range))
        {
            Debug.Log(hit.transform.name);
            Target target = hit.transform.GetComponent<Target>();

            if (target != null && target.isHit == false)
            {
                target.takeDamage(damage);
                if(hit.collider.tag == "Taggable")
                playersTagged.Add(hit.collider.gameObject);
                target.isHit = true;
            }
        }
    }
    
    public void TeleportObjectsTo(Vector3 targetPosition)
    {
        foreach(taggedObjects in playersTagged)
        {
            taggedObjects.transform.position = targetPosition;
        }
    }
}
```

You can also make the teleport happen on teleport script:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class Teleport : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform teleportTarget;
    public PlayerTagged player; // I didn't saw that you already have an ref here, my bad, so you only need to access the fields

    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {

        if (other.gameObject.tag == "Tagger")
        {
            Debug.Log("You hit the can");
            
            // Option 2:
            player.TeleportObjectsTo(teleportTarget);

            // Option 3: Or you can iterate here instead of make use of the API
            foreach(var taggedObjects in player.playersTagged)
            {
               taggedObjects.transform.position = targetPosition;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Chose one option, and delete/comment others

--N

Comment: Im not sure i quite follow?

Comment: Give another look now

Comment: I love you. I know exactly what you mean now !!! Thank you so much !!!

Comment: Nefisto. Im sorry but i thought i had it. But it seems that i dont. I have tried since your reply but i have not got the result i wanted. Could you maybe please help me a bit more with how i can teleport the objects in the list, when the player enteres the trigger.

Comment: Did you want to teleport all the objects in the list to some place?

Comment: Yes i would. All the selected in the list. When the player enteres the trigger.

Comment: Its better make the trigger happen in the player script, not in teleport, I'll edit the answer

Comment: It gives me some errors. Option 1 sounds more logical for me in this situation, but it says
that TeleportObjectsTo(teleport.teleportTarget);
"cannot convert from UnityEngine.Transform to UnityEngine.Vector3"
AND
taggedObjects does not exist in current context.

Comment: I've written this on a notepad, so this kind of thing can happen. TeleportObjectTo is expecting to receive a vector3 as a parameter and we are passing a Transform. What can we possibly do to fix it? For the second error only type an var before the taggedObjects...

Comment: Change the Vector3 in the function to a Transform?

Soooo like this ? 
foreach (var taggedObjects in playersTagged)
but will this do aswell?
taggedObjects.transform.position = targetPosition.transform.position; and then make a targetposition in the scene where they can spawn to ?

Comment: Look at the answer again, I've edited, but yes, you will need to have an empty gameobject in scene that will represent their point to teleport, this will be added into your teleport script